# How do I make PHP files automatically write to a file?

Tags: php, xampp

I've hosted websites with companies like hostgator before where if a PHP error was thrown it would write to a file in the directory of the site where the error was made. The file would be called error.log or something like that.

I would like to set this up on my local machine, does anyone know if this possible with an out of the box setup of XAMPP?

Comment: Maybe [this can help you](https://perishablepress.com/advanced-php-error-handling-via-php/).

Comment: Thanks @VictorTello this is a good start, but I'm looking for a solution that generates the error log in the directory the error occured, not a specified directory. So for example if the error occurs at 127.0.0.1/SomeDirectory/index.php then the error log would be found at 127.0.0.1/SomeDirectory/error.log.

Comment: Actually this did help, I just used a relative path in the log file path.

Comment: Glad it helped you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors)

> log_errors boolean.
>
> Tells whether script error messages should be logged to the server's error log or [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log). This option is thus server-specific.

You can probably find the `php.ini` in the `php` subfolder of the xampp installation.